# What does it mean by "Transaction Synchronized Session" with reference to Spring-Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactional, hibernateexception

Like we all know, not using the @Transactional annotation in a Spring-Hibernate application gives a Hibernate Exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: 
>   Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

I wanted to know what does it mean by "transaction synchronized session"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Session whose state is synchronized with underlying transaction. For example: after transaction is completed the session closes.

Spring manages it with `TransactionSynchronizationManager` that holds a set of `TransactionSynchronization` adapters. `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager` calls those adapters when performing different actions with transaction.

Most notable synchronization is `SpringSessionSynchronization`. Among other things it is responsible for flushing session before commit and closing session after transaction is completed.

Comment: That explains quite a lot. Thank you, also I had one more doubt. If two people separately access the same method which is annotated by @Transactional, at the same time... will there by an error? or will it execute both the DB Transactions one after the other.

Comment: If by people you mean threads then there will be no problem. Whether transactions will be executed in parallel or one after another, depends on transaction isolation level. By default transactions are able to run in parallel.